# Saving the user's response to a question posed by a bot.

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The discord user types .findtest and if certain critia is met, asks them a question. I need to save the response. For some reason the "response" getting saved is their initial ".findtest" that they typed. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
def __init__(self, bot): 
    self.bot = bot 
@commands.command(pass_context=True, pass_content=True)
async def findtest(self, ctx): 
    discord_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)


    with open(("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/DATABASE/test.json")) as f:
        data = json.load(f) 
        if discord_id in data: 
            await self.bot.say("User Found, Finding Game")
            #more code to come#

        else: 
            await self.bot.say('Type in your Display Name exactly as it appears')

            async def on_message(message, ctx, pass_context=True, pass_content=True):

                    message_d= str(ctx.message.content)


            k = {(discord_id): message_d} 


            with open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/DATABASE/test.json") as f:
                data = json.load(f) 
            data.update(k) 
            with open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/DATABASE/test.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Client.wait_for_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for_message) to get the users response to your question.  It would also make more sense for your bot to remember the contents of `data` and only open the file to update it when those contents change:

```
class Cog:
    def __init__(self, bot): 
        self.bot = bot 
        self.path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/DATABASE/test.json"
        with open(self.path) as f:
            self.data = json.load(f)

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def findtest(self, ctx): 
        discord_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)

        if discord_id in self.data: 
                await self.bot.say("User Found, Finding Game")
                #more code to come#

        else: 
            await self.bot.say('Type in your Display Name exactly as it appears')

            response = await self.bot.wait_for_message(author=ctx.message.author, 
                                                       channel=ctx.message.channel)
            message_d = response.content                
            k = {(discord_id): message_d} 
            self.data.update(k) 

            with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.data, f)
```